# Can I make child element take up the max-width while the parent component has "width: fit-content"?

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/y0jorbsf/1/

The child element has `max-width: 1000px`, because my intent is to make it take up to the 1000px width as much as it can.

However, when the parent has `width: fit-content;`, this does not work. The child always takes the **minimum** width. It seems that `max-width: 1000px` is overridden in this case.

I wonder why and how to achieve the effect: the parent still has `width: fit-content;`, and the child still takes as much as the `max-width`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: move max-width to the parent and remove the use of fit-content

Comment: @TemaniAfif would you tell me what happens in the background leading to the issue please?

Answer (score 1):

you need to move max-width to parent, and remove width:fit-content in h1 element like this

```
   div {
    height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}
```